# Would you please explain the following in details?

Tags: vocabulary

Alex had been trying to get the film made for more than twenty years.

Would anybody explain the sentence readily?

Comment: Please say which parts you understand, and which parts you do not understand. For example, “What does ‘get the film made’ mean in this sentence?” would be a better question, if that is what you want to know—although even then you'd want to explain why [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=get+the+film+made) didn't help.

Comment: To "get something done" means to accomplish a task.  To "get something made" means to accomplish an act of making.  This often implies interaction with others, as in this case.

Comment: @BobRodes But  *get something done* can also mean *cause something to be done*, as in this case. *I got my car fixed* means somebody else fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

It could mean, ...

During that period of time (which is more than twenty years), ...
Alex kept trying to turn his idea into a film, or ...
Alex kept trying to get his film making project funded, started, and finished.

The exact meaning would be easy to see once we know the context.

Comment: I think that actually nails it with or without additional context.

Comment: "being" needs to be ommitted from the example sentence, however. "Alex kept trying to get his film making project funded, started, and finished" is correct.

Comment: @BobRodes I was reluctant to say "get it funded" because the OP seems to be confused by "get it made", so I twisted my own choice of words, and then it was ungrammatical. Thank you for the comment. Edited.